# After a few hours of non-use, Ubuntu 22.04 freezes

Tags: freeze, crash, troubleshooting

I want my Ubuntu 22.04 to stay on all the time. But after a few hours of non-use, the system freezes completely, locks the mouse, keyboard, and requires a physical reboot.
How can I find out what is going on?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 16 GB RAM DDR4.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to debug these kind of issues, as most of the times its some background process that is misbehaving. Few things you can try:

1. Keep open a terminal with "top" command running, to see were processes are running / misbehaving when the system froze
2. Check running services and stop the one you don't need. Command: sudo systemctl --type=service --state=running
3. Run Driver Manager to check for updates on drivers

If the above debugging fails, then, if possible, reinstall the OS and hope the problem doesn't reoccur

Comment: The system crashs running, in the top: kworker/1:1+pm
After 12:49